# Python　配列への代入

Tags: python, chainer

python2.7を使用しています。
今、下記のコードを実行し、

```
print r.data
print r[0][action-1].data
```

> [[ 0.34642464  0.39359313 -1.24270797 -0.89923799  0.11451679 -0.49929592]]
>   -0.499295920134

と結果がでました。そこで、

```
r[0][action-1].data = 1
```

と代入を行っても

```
print r[0][action-1].data
```

> -0.499295920134

代入が反映されません。何が問題なのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。
インポートパッケージは以下です。

```
import numpy as np　　　　　　　　
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import random
import chainer
from chainer import cuda
from chainer import serializers
import chainer.functions as F
from chainer import optimizers
```

また、`print(type(r))`を入力すると、

> class 'chainer.variable.Variable'

とでます。`print　r.dtype`結果は

> float32

です。　　よろしくお願いします。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！　Python の普通の配列には `data` というメンバー変数は存在しません。`import` しているパッケージの一覧か、変数
 `r` を初期化している部分のプログラム、あるいは `print(type(r))` の結果を教えてくださいませんか？　質問文の下の「編集」から直接追記して頂けると幸いです。

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます。投稿を編集いたしましたので、ご確認ください。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: そもそもchainer.variableのdataって、直接書き換えられるのでしょうか？どういうときに直接書き換えたいのかあまりピンときてませんが、ノードの中身を直接書き換えるのって変な感じがします。

Answer (score 1):

`r[0]` とすると https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/chainer/functions/array/get_item.py#L67 が呼び出されます。
[GetItem](https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/chainer/functions/array/get_item.py#L11)というFunctionNodeが作られて、その`apply`メソッドを`r`を引数にして呼んだものが返ってきます。
つまり、スライスという操作をする計算ノードを作って適用した結果を返せ、という操作なので元のVariableが持っている`data`を共有していないのです。

書き換えたいなら

```
r.data[0][1]=0.0
```

でしょう。
CPUで実行している分には書き換わっています。GPUの場合(つまりdataが`cupy.ndarray`の場合)は分かりません。

---

ちょっと試してみた、という話でないなら「なぜそれをしたいのか?」という内容をChainerのコミュニティにあげたほうがいいかと思いました。